# How to diagnose the problem when the input assembler and the vertex shader look correrct, but the Output Merger is wrong?

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl, debugging

I'm porting some OpenGL code to Direct X 11.  I ended up with nothing being drawn on the screen. I reverted to a simple program, which I am writing about here.

I'm now trying to use the Graphics Tools in Visual Studio to diagnose a very simple "Hello Triangle" program.  In my program, I am drawing simple geometry and using a basic shader.  The shader just outputs a constant color.

```
float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT Input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

However, the Output Merger shows nothing.

**(LOOK CLOSELY)**
[image]

When I click on the output merger, I see a green alpha checkerboard.

[image]

What I would like to know ultimately, is what I'm doing wrong. (Why is the output merger basically blank?)  Additionally, I'd like to learn some skill in reading outputs like this:

[image]

This is the contents of `basic.hlsl`

```
cbuffer cbTransform : register( b0 )
{
    matrix matWorldViewProj;
};

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 Position     : POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoord     : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal       : NORMAL;
    float4 Color        : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position     : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord     : TEXCOORD0;    
    float3 Normal       : NORMAL;
    float4 Color        : COLOR0;
};

VS_OUTPUT vs_main( VS_INPUT Input )
{
    VS_OUTPUT Output;
    Output.Position = mul(float4(Input.Position,1), matWorldViewProj);
    Output.TexCoord = Input.TexCoord;
    Output.Normal = mul(Input.Normal, (float3x3)matWorldViewProj);
    Output.Color = Input.Color;
    return( Output );
}

float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT Input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here's what matWorldViewProj looks like:

[image]

Comment: what's your vertex shader? looks like your vertices all disappear after the vertex shader. Have you not set SV_Position? What's your VS_OUTPUT and how do you fill it?

Comment: Updated question with entire shader

Comment: have you ***verified*** that your matWorldViewProj matrix is ok? I'd start from there.

Comment: Updated with a picture of matWorldViewProj

Comment: Updated with adjustments recommended by Babis

Answer (score 0):

Fix your matWorldViewProj. w values are NaN, so the transformation will fail miserably. The w column should be (0,0,0,1).

Also, you should be getting complaints at the following line:

```
Output.Position = mul(Input.Position, matWorldViewProj);
```

as you multiply a 4x4 matrix with a float3. Change it to:

```
Output.Position = mul(float4(Input.Position,1), matWorldViewProj);
```

and **fix** the w values in C++ code.

Comment: Still didn't work.  I adjusted the HLSL code though.  Thanks.  The matWorldViewProj matrix is actually just set to the identity matrix in the C code all this time.  When I fixed the HLSL code, the full identity matrix is coming across now.  I updated the question with the new picture.

Comment: So far so good, now I think the culprit might be the render target view. Is there any chance to see the C++ file? **More importantly**, if you run the program with debugging and you break just after the render, do you get any D3D related error message in the output window?

Comment: No D3D related error messages.  (I know what you mean -- I have the debugging layer turned on and I've used the messages thus far as I fumbled my way through the D3D API)  Is there a way to private email one another for the code?